# websphere welcome-file filter not getting picked up

Tags: java, websphere, web.xml, welcome-file

Below are contents of my web.xml, application is depployed in websphere 8.5

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Issue I am facing is my CheckFilter is not getting invoked when i am hitting the url like https://servername:portNumber/contextPath/?QueryParam
Same is working fine on tomcat & weblogic.

But if i enter url https://servername:portNumber/contextPath/index.jsp?QueryParam

My filter is getting invoked.To get the response for first url what should i need to change.

i.e. without giving the index.jsp filter should get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two options depending on your requirements

1) Add urlpattern on `/` like this (since if you call just the application context there is no index.jsp in the pattern)

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RootFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

2) Since the request is *forwarded* to the `index.jsp`, you can add `FORWARD` to your filter mapping, like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RootFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: So you have something wrong with your app, as both work correctly on my sample app. Check your web.xml (maybe attach complete) and logs (maybe you have some errors there).

Comment: Hi @Gas, I found that, in both the URLs the index.jsp is getting called. But the the one without index.jsp in url , does not call the filter and directly calls the index.jsp. And the other in which index.jsp is present, calls filter first and then index.jsp

Comment: hi @Gas, I have added below in <filter-mapping> <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern> and then narrowed down to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>. Has solved my problem. Thanks for your help.